# SpringMVC with javaconfig PropertySource failed

Tags: java, spring

code is below:

```
public class RootInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.wasu.accounting.service")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath*:/test.properties")
public class RootConfig {
 @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        return new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

### project structure

[image: project structure]

when I start tomcat,get some error below :

> class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.test.accounting.config.RootConfig];
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open
>   ServletContext resource [/classpath*:/test.properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/test.properties")
```

and make sure the file is on the classpath (under your resources folder).

Comment: yep，when i change classpath* to classpath ,the problem is resolved.
thank you